# Pandas convert datatime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame extract from excel file with a date.
The original date in excel is in this format (dd/mm/yyyy)

`20/05/2020`

but, in my code, if I print the date column, the format date is changed (yyyy-mm-dd)

`2020-05-20`

When I copy the dataframe in another preformatted sheet excel, the date has converted in yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss

`2020-05-20 00:00:00`

In the preformatted sheet, the date column is setting with format "dd/mm/yyyy".

I have try to use the to_datetime, but this not work for me.

```
df.Workdate = pd.to_datetime(df.Workdate.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

or

```
df['Workdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Workdate'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

The result not change, if I print the df, the date have every the same format yyyy-mm-dd (in excel yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss).

Where am i wrong?

Regards, 
Marco

Comment: how do you copy the data from the dataframe to Excel?

Comment: Output is expected, in python is default format of datetimes `yyyy-mm-dd`, if need another format use `strftime`, but then lost datetimes (get strings).

Comment: So if need custom format `'%d/%m/%Y'` and also datetimes (not strings) is is impossible

Comment: Ok, this work!
df['Workdate'] = df.Workdate.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

Thanks!